# Recursion when calling Owner in Groovy Closure

Tags: groovy

I have been trying to understand Groovy scripts but an example I made is hitting an unexpected StackOverflow.

The foo closure prints out its owner as 'Tank', before defining another closure
named bar.  I expected bar to print the owner as something like Tank$foo.

```
class Tank {
    def foo = {
        println "Owner is $owner"

        def bar = {
            println "      Owner is $owner"
        }
        bar()
    }

    static void main(String ...args){
        def t = new Tank() ;
        t.foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: in bar, instead of embedding $owner in the gstring, move it outside "Owner is " + owner

Comment: The comment from @MikeW has stopped the recursion.  I still would like a more detailed reasoning explained.

Comment: Please see my detailed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... The short answer is you should change your `bar` method to the following:

```
def bar = {
    println "      Owner is ${owner.toString()}"
}
```

That will prevent the `foo` closure referenced by the `$owner` from evaluation. Because it will no longer be a closure but rather a string representation of it. This is what you want to achieve in your example.

The **full answer** is bit too complicated and has its history...

String interpolation in Groovy is implemented using the `GString` class. When the compiler comes across your `"      Owner is $owner"` it first breaks that value into different pieces where the `"      Owner is "` is kept as a `string` whereas `$owner` goes to the so-called values. This is how an instance of [`GString` gets constructed](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/GStringImpl.java#L48), it's a combination of those two pieces.

If we then look into the Groovy source code, we can see how the [`GString.toString()`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/groovy/lang/GString.java#L153) is evaluated. The existing implementation iterates over the both arrays, `strings` and `values`, and if the `value` is a closure then it just eagerly evaluates (calls) that. This is why you fall into the infinite recursion in your example. Here is the snippet of `GString.toString()` found in [Groovy source code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/groovy/lang/GString.java#L172) (spot the `c.call(...)`):

```
if (value instanceof Closure) {
    final Closure c = (Closure) value;

    if (c.getMaximumNumberOfParameters() == 0) {
        InvokerHelper.write(out, c.call());
    } else if (c.getMaximumNumberOfParameters() == 1) {
        c.call(out);
    } else {
        throw new GroovyRuntimeException("Trying to evaluate a GString containing a Closure taking "
                + c.getMaximumNumberOfParameters() + " parameters");
    }
} else {
    InvokerHelper.write(out, value);
}
```

Interestingly, I also found when this was first introduced and the discussion about potentially changing this behaviour. The discussion issue is still open.

- [GROOVY-1665 Allow Closures to be lazily evaluated in GStrings](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1665) - the existing implementation introduced back in 2007.
- [GROOVY-8952 Eager interpolation evaluating as a Closure does a lazy invoke of the Closure](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8952) - discussion about changing this behaviour.